# Can't get multiple parameters to controller to work

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, parameters, controller

Here's the jquery from my view:

```
 $("#btnSelect1").click(function () {
        var donationTypeID = $(this).closest('p').find('#selectList').val();
        var id = parseInt(donationTypeID);
        var id2 = $('#person').val();
        var persId = parseInt(id2);

        // var personName 
        var route = '/Donation/ContinueDonation/' + id + '?personId =' + persId;

        $("#donationSection1").load(route, function () {...});...
```

Here's the controller method

```
 public ActionResult ContinueDonation(int id, int personId)
    {}
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this to work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think the previous answer is not all that right. Your query string is correct if it were hitting the default route established by MVC which matches a URL something like this {controller}/{action}/{id}.

What must really be going on is that you messed with the routes and your query is either not hitting the default route or you changed that.

What I would do is get the RouteDebugger (just get it via nuget) and see which route your query string hits. You could setup a route for any URL you want it to be (sort of the whole point of friendly URLs), so If you want the route to be /ContinueGiving/{id}/{personId} you can do that by adding a route to the beginning of the routes getting added with a definition something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ContinueDonation",
    url: "ContinueGiving/{id}/{personId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Donation", action = "ContinueDonation" },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+", personId = @"\d+" }
);
```

Any parameters you do not specify will get mapped if the framework can find any matching items in either posted values, the query string, etc.

The constraints make sure this route only gets matched if the parameters passed are numbers.

So the previous answer worked because somehow the route with id didn't match, but that is not really your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give a key to the id value:

```
var route = '/Donation/ContinueDonation/?id=' + id + '&personId =' + persId;
```

---

BTW, the `var persId = parseInt(id2);` line is redundant, as every parameter sent with HTTP is a string, so `"234"` and `234` are exactly the same.

Comment: @redBarron This format will for for every number of parameters.